# How can i check a radio button by clicking on asp text field using javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

Hi
While working on asp, i want if i click on my asp text field, a radio button should be checked, but i dont find any onClick event available for asp text field, and if i use onchange, it is from the server end, i want this situation without page refresh, just like we do in html fields using javascript, please help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this one:**

**HTML:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSelect" runat="server" Width="200px" Text="Click here"> </asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radCheck" runat="server" />
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("#txtSelect").click(function(){
    $("#radCheck").attr("checked",true);
});
```

Comment: An aspx text field is the same as a HTML text field in the browser. Are you saying that when the user clicks the textbox, the page should postback to the server which then forces the radio button to be checked?

Comment: I dont want page refresh! i think asp text box does not have the property of click.

Answer (score 0):

OnFocus is probably the event I would use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax if you don't wanna refresh the page